# Janus-gateway "join" http call return "ack" only

Tags: javascript, janus-gateway

I am new to Janus with javascript, I have a room like this:

```
{
    "janus": "success",
    "session_id": 266646464364358,
    "transaction": "MUcPg6Wu5jhr",
    "sender": 4377145860586972,
    "plugindata": {
        "plugin": "janus.plugin.videoroom",
        "data": {
            "videoroom": "success",
            "list": [
                {
                    "room": 11,
                    "description": "Room 11",
                    "pin_required": false,
                    "is_private": false,
                    "max_publishers": 3,
                    "bitrate": 0,
                    "fir_freq": 0,
                    "require_pvtid": false,
                    "require_e2ee": false,
                    "dummy_publisher": false,
                    "notify_joining": false,
                    "audiocodec": "opus",
                    "videocodec": "vp8",
                    "opus_fec": true,
                    "record": false,
                    "lock_record": false,
                    "num_participants": 0,
                    "audiolevel_ext": true,
                    "audiolevel_event": false,
                    "videoorient_ext": true,
                    "playoutdelay_ext": true,
                    "transport_wide_cc_ext": true
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

THen I using join request with body like this:

```
join params {
  janus: 'message',
  plugin: 'janus.plugin.videoroom',
  session_id: 8568607942621781,
  handle_id: 3267543887867048,
  transaction: 'VeENHRbBTHWI',
  body: { request: 'join', room: 11, ptype: 'publisher', display: 'test' }
}
```

But the response is `ack` only, I dont know why it's not return `joined` event, can someone help?

```
{
    "janus": "ack",
    "session_id": 8568607942621781,
    "transaction": "VeENHRbBTHWI"
}
```

Note that after this, I checked the participants inside room but it's still empty:

```
{
    "janus": "success",
    "session_id": 4397550774641519,
    "transaction": "h8LgvUJxVXGk",
    "sender": 8580331991428173,
    "plugindata": {
        "plugin": "janus.plugin.videoroom",
        "data": {
            "videoroom": "participants",
            "room": 11,
            "participants": []
        }
    }
}
```

All my https call work nomally(such as create video room/ destroy, listroom, list participants,...) but only `joinroom` api have trouble, here is my javascript code:

```js
joinRoom = async(options) => {
        await this.ensureAttachedToSessionId()
        const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const params = {
                janus: 'message',
                plugin: this.plugin,
                session_id: this.sessionID,
                handle_id: this.handleID,
                transaction: JanusUtils.randomString(12),
                body: {
                    request: 'join',
                    ...options
                }
            }
            console.log('join params', params)
            fetch(this.janusUrl, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(params),
                ...JanusUtils.defaultHeader()
            }).then(result => result.json())
            .then(result => {
                resolve(result) 
            })
            .catch(error => { reject(error) })
        })
        return promise
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get that "ack" response you can use GET `/janus/12345678` endpoint to get the "joined" event you expect. 12345678 - is your session ID. This is because requests like "join" are async. This what the docs say.

> The join , joinandconfigure , configure , publish , unpublish , start , pause , switch and leave requests instead are all asynchronous, which means you'll get a notification about their success or failure in an event.
> You can heck it out at https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/videoroom

Also check this article https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/rest.htm. This is shows how to use Janus REST API

You can establish a long polling request to poll for events. However, I would recomment to take a look on Janode. https://github.com/meetecho/janode.
It has great examples built in JS.

Comment: Hi I saw this guide: `If you receive this ack instead of a "success" response, you can be sure the plugin has received the message, and is going to process it soon`, so it's mean "ack" is just alert user that janus system has get the request, not done the request. Actually we want to know when request is done when using API

Comment: @famfamfam I understand. I had the same problem just day ago. In order to do this "Actually we want to know when request is done when using API" you just need to make GET request to /janus/{your_session_in} after you made POST request to join. You need to undestand that your "join" request may not be processed as you pushed it to Janus. In order to know when your "join" request is actually processed you need to send that GET endpoint and check in the response whether it's processed or not. Also you can use WebSockets